# Incorrect java -version on command prompt

Tags: java

I already had JDK 5 on my machine. I have updated JDK  by installing Java Development Kit 7.  Now, I have set the Path and JAVA_HOME variables as per latest Java. but still "java -version" showing me older version.

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.5.0_07"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_07-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 1.5.0_07-b03, mixed mode)
```

Please see the current states of my environment variables as below:

```
C:\>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\

C:\>echo %Path%
C:\WINNT\system32;C:\WINNT;C:\WINNT\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Barclays Capital\CommonApi\bin\
;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging\;C:\WINNT\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICAService\;C:\Program Files\Citrix\Syst
em32\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files\Barclays Capital\P4CustomTools;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.0
.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\AGL;C:\Apps\oracle\product\10.2.0.3\client\bin;C:\Apps\oracle\product\10.2.0\client\BIN;C:\APPS\o
racle\client\11.2.0.3\home1\bin;C:\WINNT\system32\;C:\WINNT\;C:\WINNT\system32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Windows Imaging;C:\Program Files\Java\j
dk1.7.0_03\bin

C:\>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_03
```

I know how to change the environment variable and I have referred other post on stack overflow.

What should be reason behind incorrect path returned by `java -version` command ?

Comment: The java exe is in the JRE but the javac exe is in the JDK.  Looks like your JRE is in the path before the JDK.

Comment: Thanks ! I have given the whole Path in question. Can you please advise solution over this ?

Comment: update path and JAVA_HOME variable

Comment: Yes, put C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin at the beginning of the path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When installing a public `JRE` (used by the Java plugin), a java.exe file is also created in `C:\WINNT\system32` (IIRC). It's probably this java command that is executed, since `C:\WINNT\system32` comes before the `JDK/bin` directory in your PATH.

Put the JDK/bin directory at the beginning of the `PATH`.

Comment: Perfect ! This resolved my issue !

Comment: Also to check order you can execute `where java` in command prompt

Comment: Is this windows command ?

Comment: yes. and `which` is an analog for linux